# Freemarker+ExtJS vs Wicket

Tags: extjs, wicket, freemarker

I have been developing for a while using Freemarker + some JS frameworks (like ExtJS). Now I hear lots of talks about Wicket so Im trying to understand pros and cons. After reading intro in Wicket I have mixed feelings. Below are my conclusions. I know Im biased but dont take it as offence. Instead rather as misunderstanding since Im really trying to see if Wicket is thing to switch to:

Seems like this is good for companies where you have Java programmers that you can now utilize for building Front-end. On other hand, as Front-end developer this looks weird to me since I feel like I dont have full control of JScript code.

1. Since Wicket uses Java for generating HTML/CSS/JScript UI controls for me meaning if I need to tweak those controls outside of their box it maybe problematic. In my experience any framework good until you start doing something different from what it was intended and then you can spend more effort trying to do simple out of box thing then using native JScript. Is there JScript sources for Wicket controls?
2. Prototyping: using Freemarker I can do changes and simply refresh page. In case of Wicket I need to recompile.
3. Logic blocks: Looks like Wicket allows injection of values into HTML tags with wicket: attribute but how do you handle block logic like IF(condition) then {use HTML block1} else { use another HTML block}?
4. Non html data templating: often during page generation I compose some AJAX data from FreeMarker inside  tag. How do I do similar things from Wicket?
5. Is it harder/simpler to create custom UI controls in Wicket?

Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Freemarker or JS isn't a web framework. 
What do You use? A raw Servlet? Your comparison seems strange.

In Wicket You can use templating, built-in Velocity Panel, or find or build Freemarker panel. Coding such kind of Panel needs a few hours (for an active Wicket programmer), but then you can reuse it many times. The Injected (from Panels) HTML part must be valid, html tags closed etc.

3) Wicket hasn't if-else construction in markup. Maybe use Comcoment.setVisible(false), or very good made loop's (few repeaters: https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/reference-library.html Look at examples).

Comment: your link doesn't work and ExtJS is a well known Javascript framework from Sencha